# Wireless network continously disconnects

Tags: wireless

I have pavilion g6 with ubuntu 12.04 installed , My wireless networks keeps on disconnecting and then takes a long time to connect
Can someone suggest a possible solution for this problem ?

Here are the output of some commands that might be useful to solve the problem

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA 
Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)

07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

07:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth

08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI 

Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)

09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

lsmod

```
vboxpci                23236  0 

vboxnetadp             25670  0 

vboxnetflt             27612  0 

vboxdrv               320274  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt

binfmt_misc            17508  1 

pci_stub               12622  1 

coretemp               17728  0 

nvram                  14462  0 

bnep                   23966  2 

rfcomm                 74658  0 

bluetooth             391597  10 bnep,rfcomm

parport_pc             32866  0 

ppdev                  17711  0 

snd_hda_codec_hdmi     41684  1 

snd_hda_codec_idt      55098  1 

uvcvideo               82247  0 

snd_hda_intel          57183  3 

snd_hda_codec         194881  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel

arc4                   12573  2 

videobuf2_core         40903  1 uvcvideo

snd_hwdep              13613  1 snd_hda_codec

snd_pcm               107140  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec

videodev              139144  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core

videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo

videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc

snd_seq_midi           13324  0 

snd_rawmidi            30465  1 snd_seq_midi

rt2800pci              18966  0 

rt2x00mmio             13661  1 rt2800pci

radeon               1540281  0 

rt2800lib              95449  1 rt2800pci

snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi

crc_ccitt              12707  1 rt2800lib

rt2x00pci              13287  1 rt2800pci

ttm                    84699  1 radeon

rt2x00lib              56053  4 rt2800pci,rt2x00mmio,rt2800lib,rt2x00pci

i915                  733900  3 

snd_seq                66061  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event

snd_timer              30038  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq

hp_wmi                 18202  0 

joydev                 17575  0 

snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq

mac80211              634700  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib

sparse_keymap          13890  1 hp_wmi

cfg80211              504229  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211

drm_kms_helper         53165  2 radeon,i915

drm                   303133  6 radeon,ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper


mei_me                 18418  0 

snd                    73802  17 

snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_se

q_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device

psmouse               104113  0 

mei                    78609  1 mei_me


soundcore              12680  1 snd

snd_page_alloc         18798  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm

rtsx_pci_ms            18320  0 

memstick               16762  1 rtsx_pci_ms

hp_accel               26012  0 

wmi                    19363  1 hp_wmi

i2c_algo_bit           13564  2 radeon,i915
serio_raw              13462  0 
video                  19574  1 i915

eeprom_93cx6           13344  1 rt2800pci

lis3lv02d              20280  1 hp_accel

input_polldev          13896  1 lis3lv02d

mac_hid                13253  0 

lpc_ich                21163  0 

lp                     17799  0 

parport                42481  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp

rtsx_pci_sdmmc         23920  0 

ahci                   30063  2 

libahci                32088  1 ahci

rtsx_pci               46133  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc

r8169                  73111  0 

mii                    13981  1 r8169
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network               

   description: Wireless interface


   product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

   vendor: Ralink corp.

   physical id: 0

   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0

   logical name: wlan0

   version: 00

   serial: a4:17:31:43:c1:61

   width: 32 bits

   clock: 33MHz

   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless

   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.12.0-031200rc7-
   generic firmware=0.37 ip=10.39.216.234 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless =IEEE 
   802.11bgn

   resources: irq:16 memory:63510000-6351ffff

  *-network

   description: Ethernet interface

   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller

   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.

   physical id: 0

   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0

   logical name: eth0

   version: 05

   serial: 84:34:97:8b:40:ef

   size: 100Mbit/s

   capacity: 100Mbit/s

   width: 64 bits

   clock: 33MHz

   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 
    mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation

   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 
    driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw     ip=10.171.50.69 
      latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s

   resources: irq:43 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:63404000-63404fff 
   memory:63400000-63403fff
```

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7510986/

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7510986/
Here is the output of running the below command as suggested in the link given by you 


wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && \
chmod +x wireless_script && \
./wireless_script

Answer (score 0):

Get this from the link through and connect ethernet cable connected to your computer. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/ndisgtk/ It should tell you what to do when you open it. You probably have a bad driver.